# Access front end GUI

Tags: sql, user-interface, frontend

I have a small SQL database, I want to make a front end GUI for it. VERY basic kind of stuff that basically just allows the user to input data into the GUI which basically just inserts data into the tables from the SQL database. I have the SQL database loaded into Access. I split the database which i think I was supposed to do?? Not sure If i was wrong let me know.

I think I need to usa Visual basic to make the page? I tried tinkering around but I cant seem to find the right instructions online.  I basically am just trying to make an Access front end with a GUI that has a couple text boxes that the user will input data into, which will then save into the data to the back end SQL.

Anyone have any direction then can help point me? or if im am just COMPLETELY wrong in doing this that would also be nice to know lol I just thought Ive seen this done somewhere.

Comment: What can't you use Access to do the GUI?

Comment: Access will do this all for you. Click on one of your linked tables on the front end file, and click the create form wizard. `voila`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your linked tables in Access that link to SQLServer should have the globe icons like this picture: 

[image: Linked tables picture]

This means they're linked to the server rather than imported in as a copy of the data. Be sure the tables have primary keys, too; if they're heap tables (ie, no clustered unique index) then the linked tables will be read-only, because Access doesn't know how to send an update query to SQLServer. You can test this by opening one of the linked tables and trying to change data; your cursor won't do anything if it's a read-only table.
To create a super-basic entry form linked to a table, click Insert>Form, then right-click the little square in the upper-left corner of the form and click Properties like this:

[image: Access form]

Select the table that you want this form to do edits on in the RecordSource property as shown below. You can click the "..." to make a query rather than a single table for the edits, like if you need to join tables, but this gets more complicated because Access gets particular about what queries are still editable and frequently treats the query as read-only if you don't meet all the requirements (for ex, union queries will be read-only):

[image: query]

After you set the RecordSource, click View>Field List and you'll see the fields from the table like this:
[image: fields]

Highlight these fields and drag them to the form like this (the unique key fields like ProductID should usually be made invisible, especially if they're autonumber fields, b/c the database will set these, not the user):

[image: drag]

Click View>Form View, and you've got yourself an entry form. Use the left-right arrows at the bottom to move through the records, and the asterisk button to create a new record.
[image: entry form]